# Missing "Buyer Information" in Recurring Payment

Tags: paypal

We're using the PayPal PHP SDK to create a "Recurring Payments Profile", but every profile is missing the "Buyer Information" (Name & Email) under "History" in our Sandbox account.

How can we add the buyer's name and email address to the request?

```
$firstName = $_POST[ 'firstName' ];
$lastName = $_POST[ 'lastName' ];
$email = $_POST[ 'email' ];

$installment_amount = ...;

$shippingAddress = new AddressType();
$shippingAddress->Name = $firstName . ' ' . $lastName;
$shippingAddress->Street1 = $_POST[ 'address1' ];
$shippingAddress->Street2 = $_POST[ 'address2' ];
$shippingAddress->CityName = $_POST[ 'city' ];
$shippingAddress->StateOrProvince = $_POST[ 'state' ];
$shippingAddress->PostalCode = $_POST[ 'zip' ];
$shippingAddress->Country = $_POST[ 'country' ];
$shippingAddress->Phone = $_POST[ 'phone' ];

$RPProfileDetails = new RecurringPaymentsProfileDetailsType();
$RPProfileDetails->SubscriberName = $firstName . ' ' . $lastName;
$RPProfileDetails->BillingStartDate = date( DATE_ATOM );
$RPProfileDetails->SubscriberShippingAddress = $shippingAddress;

$activationDetails = new ActivationDetailsType();
$activationDetails->InitialAmount = new BasicAmountType( 'USD', $installment_amount );
$activationDetails->FailedInitialAmountAction = 'CancelOnFailure';

$paymentBillingPeriod = new BillingPeriodDetailsType();
$paymentBillingPeriod->BillingFrequency = 1;
$paymentBillingPeriod->BillingPeriod = 'Day';
$paymentBillingPeriod->TotalBillingCycles = 2;
$paymentBillingPeriod->Amount = new BasicAmountType( 'USD', $installment_amount );

$scheduleDetails = new ScheduleDetailsType();
$scheduleDetails->Description = ...;
$scheduleDetails->ActivationDetails = $activationDetails;
$scheduleDetails->PaymentPeriod = $paymentBillingPeriod;
$scheduleDetails->MaxFailedPayments = 3;
$scheduleDetails->AutoBillOutstandingAmount = 'AddToNextBilling';

$createRPProfileRequestDetail = new CreateRecurringPaymentsProfileRequestDetailsType();

$cardDetails = new CreditCardDetailsType();
$cardDetails->CreditCardNumber = $_POST[ 'creditCardNumber' ];
$cardDetails->CreditCardType = $_POST[ 'creditCardType' ];
$cardDetails->ExpMonth = $_POST[ 'expDateMonth' ];
$cardDetails->ExpYear = $_POST[ 'expDateYear' ];
$cardDetails->CVV2 = $_POST[ 'cvv2Number' ];

$createRPProfileRequestDetail->CreditCard = $cardDetails;
$createRPProfileRequestDetail->ScheduleDetails = $scheduleDetails;
$createRPProfileRequestDetail->RecurringPaymentsProfileDetails = $RPProfileDetails;

$createRPProfileRequest = new CreateRecurringPaymentsProfileRequestType();
$createRPProfileRequest->CreateRecurringPaymentsProfileRequestDetails = $createRPProfileRequestDetail;

$createRPProfileReq = new CreateRecurringPaymentsProfileReq();
$createRPProfileReq->CreateRecurringPaymentsProfileRequest = $createRPProfileRequest;

$paypalService = new PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService( ... );

try {

    $createRPProfileResponse = $paypalService->CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile( $createRPProfileReq );

} catch ( Exception $exception ) {

    ...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are passing the shipping information in the Profile Details it should get passed into the transaction information in Sandbox. Billing address is not stored in the PayPal Transactions.
Your code looks like it should be passing the information correctly. As a just in case, look over the below sample code from GitHub. I didn't paste all of the code in.

[Merchant SDK php Sample for Recurring Billing](https://github.com/paypal/merchant-sdk-php/blob/256ba68ce57f7b169e4f0d3cb5ea04c582f4a295/samples/RecurringPayments/CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile.php)

```
$shippingAddress = new AddressType();
$shippingAddress->Name = $_REQUEST['shippingName'];
$shippingAddress->Street1 = $_REQUEST['shippingStreet1'];
$shippingAddress->Street2 = $_REQUEST['shippingStreet2'];
$shippingAddress->CityName = $_REQUEST['shippingCity'];
$shippingAddress->StateOrProvince = $_REQUEST['shippingState'];
$shippingAddress->PostalCode = $_REQUEST['shippingPostalCode'];
$shippingAddress->Country = $_REQUEST['shippingCountry'];
$shippingAddress->Phone = $_REQUEST['shippingPhone'];

$RPProfileDetails = new RecurringPaymentsProfileDetailsType();
$RPProfileDetails->SubscriberName = $_REQUEST['subscriberName'];
$RPProfileDetails->BillingStartDate = $_REQUEST['billingStartDate'];
$RPProfileDetails->SubscriberShippingAddress = $shippingAddress;

$activationDetails = new ActivationDetailsType();
```